# Column ambigously defined

Tags: oracle

Am having issue executing the below.

> line 1: ORA-00918: column ambiguously defined

```
SELECT
user_id, user_no,dat_sys,dat_post from rec_txnlog
LEFT JOIN rec_bctl ON user_id = user_no
ORDER BY
  2 DESC;
```

Comment: One (or more) of the field names used in the query (`user_id`, `user_no`, `dat_sys` or `dat_post`) exists in both tables (`rec_txnlog` and `rec_bctl`). Specify table alias for each field in a query. Or for those field at least.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fix this:

```
SELECT
    a.user_id, a.user_no, a.dat_sys, a.dat_post 
FROM 
    rec_txnlog a
    LEFT JOIN rec_bctl b 
    ON 
        a.user_id = b.user_no
ORDER BY
    a.user_no DESC;
```

The mistakes you'll encounter are either of the form `ORA-00904 invalid identifier "dat_sys"`, in which case change the `a` to `b`

Or the wrong data will be showing for that column, and again, change the `a` to `b`

Tips:
Always, always, always alias your tables. Always use the alias when referring to columns. One day you'll write a massive query, not use aliases, it'll work.. Then you'll later join in some other table with a clashing column name, and have a lot of fun trying to work out what went wrong where

Do not use numeric indexes in orderby, use names